# Updating ListView (With realm) when navigator.pop

Tags: listview, react-native, realm

I nearly finished my application but it remains one major problem :

When I used navigator.pop, my ListView doesn't update.

**ListView**

```
<ListView
    enableEmptySections={true}
    style={styles.listView}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} navigator={this.props.navigator} />}
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
/>
```

**ListBillScreen.js**

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 var bdd = [];
 const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
 this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(bdd),
  realm: this.props.billsbdd.realm,
  db: bdd,
  };
}

componentWillUpdate () {
  this.setState = {
  realm: this.props.billsbdd.realm
}
}

componentDidMount() {

  BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress', () =>
    this.popIfExists()
  );

  realms = this.state.realm;

  if(realms == ""){
    src = [];
  }
  else{
    src =  this.state.realm.objects('Bills');
  }

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(src)
  })

}
```

**AddBillScreen.js**

```
  handlePressCreate() {
  //TODO: Creation of a bill

    let realms = this.state.realm;

    realms.write(() => {
      realms.create('Bills', {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        type: this.state.billType,
        creditor: this.state.billCreditor,
        month: this.state.billMonth,
        year: this.state.billYear,
        price: this.state.billPrice,
      })
    });
    alert("Facture créée ! ");

    this.props.navigator.pop();
```

}

I would like, when I press the back button that my ListView is rendering itself with new datas.
I have to go back again each time and reconnect to see my ListView updated.
I tried some of popular solutions on stackoverlflow but none of them are easy for me ... 
If someone can help me that will be so great of you ! Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer !

I need to add

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
 realms = this.state.realm;

if(realms == ""){
  src = [];
}
else{
  src =  this.state.realm.objects('Bills');
}

this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(src)
})
}
```

in **ListBillScreen.js** to make it work !